# How i can run selenium C# test cases in order one by one?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-development-server

I have written several test cases using selenium web drivers in C#.
I have used ORDER attribute to run the test cases in order. It is run by order. But tests does not wait for prior tests to finish.

I have used WebDriverWait also. But it does not wait.

Reference Link: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Order-Attribute

Please find the below code snippet:

```
[Test, Order(1)]
    public void OpenUserPage()
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, new TimeSpan(2000));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("NavigationMenu")));

            var userPageEle = _webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("icon-Users"));
            userPageEle.Click();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SendMail.SendErrorEmail(e.StackTrace, "OpenUserPage()");
        }
    }

    [Test, Order(2)]
    public void AddUser()
    {
        try
        {
            var waitForAddUser= new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, new TimeSpan(5000));
            waitForAddUser.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("[ng-click*=AddUserBtnClick]")));

            var addUser = _webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-click*=AddUserBtnClick]"));
            addUser.Click();

            var element = _webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='Role_hidden']"));
            var permissionSet = _webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='RolePermissionSet_hidden']"));

            var FirstName = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("FirstName"));
            FirstName.SendKeys("Sangeetha");

            var LastName = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("Last Name"));
            LastName.SendKeys("Periyaiah");

            var UserName = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("UserName"));
            UserName.SendKeys("SangeetheP");

            var Password = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("Password"));
            Password.SendKeys("Sync@123");

            var Email = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("Email"));
            Email.SendKeys("sangee900@gmail.com");

            var RoleList = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("RoleList"));
            element.SendKeys("SuperAdmin");

            var RolePermissionList = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("RolePermissionList"));
            permissionSet.SendKeys("SuperAdmin");

            var MobileNumber = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("MobileNumber"));
            MobileNumber.SendKeys("8220867882");

            var AreaCode = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("AreaCode"));
            AreaCode.SendKeys("600002");

            var Address = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("Address"));
            Address.SendKeys("3/761, Ab Block");

            var submit = _webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-click*=AddUpdateUser]"));
            submit.Click();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SendMail.SendErrorEmail(e.StackTrace, "AddUser()");
        }
    }

    [Test, Order(3)]
    public void ApplyFilter()
    {
        try
        {
            var waitForSearch = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, new TimeSpan(55000));
            waitForSearch.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(".form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid")));

            var searchUser = _webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid"));
            searchUser.SendKeys("as");

            var waitFilter = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, new TimeSpan(55000));
            waitFilter.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable((By.CssSelector("[ng-click*=filterUserBtnClick]"))));

            var applyUserFilter = _webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-click*=filterUserBtnClick]"));
            applyUserFilter.Click();

            var waitResetFilter = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, new TimeSpan(55000));
            waitResetFilter.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable((By.CssSelector("[ng-click*=resetFilter]"))));

            var resetFilter = _webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-click*=resetFilter]"));
            resetFilter.Click();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SendMail.SendErrorEmail(e.StackTrace, "ApplyFilter()");
        }
    }
```

Please share any other solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.

Selenium web driver provides a callback which tries to find the targeted element in the mintues/seconds/hours given.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

Func<IWebDriver, bool> waitForElement = new Func<IWebDriver, bool>((IWebDriver Web) =>
{
     Console.WriteLine(Web.FindElement(By.Id("target")).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
     return true;
});
wait.Until(waitForElement);
```

Reference Link:
https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/advance-explicit-webdriver-waits-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned the exact outcome of the test cases but after going though codes i would suggest two ways to solve it.

1. If webdriverwait code line throw some exception and it doesn't work then you can refer following code

   ```
      var waitForAddUser= new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, new TimeSpan(5000));
        waitForAddUser.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException),
                typeof(ElementNotVisibleException));
       waitForAddUser.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("[ng- 
              click*=AddUserBtnClick]")));
   ```
2. Use  [Setup()]CommonWait() { Thread.sleep(5000)); }